# Unhandled rejection RequestError: The conversion of the nvarchar value '238998679919674' overflowed an int column

Tags: sql-server, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js, tedious

I have table 'customers'

[image]

and table 'conversations'

[image]

I am pretty new in javascript. Currently, I try to use knex + bookshelf (SQL server database with tedious driver) to join those two tables. I separate those two tables in two models and call it from a router (I use Node js).

> conversation.js
>
> ```
> customer: function() {
>   return this.belongsTo('Customer','uniqueid');
> }
> ```
>
> customer.js
>
> ```
> conversation: function(){
>   return this.hasMany('Conversation','customer_id');
> }
> ```

When I try to join the tables as

```
Customer.fetchAll({withRelated:['conversation'], debug: true}).then(function(data{
  console.log('data : '+data);
});
```

Unfortunately, I always get the error:

> Unhandled rejection RequestError: The conversion of the nvarchar value
>   '238998679919674' overflowed an int column.

I curious about where is the error come from? since the columns' type is nvarchar, not int.

The the debug's result is

```
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [],
  __knexQueryUid: '7befdc84-c66c-4278-b88c-d53a306c36db',
  sql: 'select [customers].* from [customers]' }
GET /ticket/list 500 16 - 21.899 ms
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: 
   [ 1,
     2,
     3,
     4,
     5,
     6,
     7,
     8,
     9,
     10,
     11,
     12,
     13,
     14,
     15,
     16,
     17,
     18,
     19,
     20,
     21,
     22,
     23,
     24,
     25,
     26,
     27,
     28,
     29,
     30,
     31,
     32,
     33,
     34,
     35,
     36,
     37,
     38,
     39,
     40,
     41,
     42,
     43,
     44,
     45,
     46,
     47,
     48,
     49,
     50 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '29ca9239-b7af-4765-95b1-836ed2c570ce',
  sql: 'select [conversations].* from [conversations] where [conversations].[customer_id] in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' }
```

Comment: You can debug your code and find a bad row

Comment: I edited the post and put the debug's result

Answer (score 0):

You try to join two tables on customer id, right? In the first table (customers) id is int, in the second customer_id is nvarchar. When you join int to nvarchar, the nvarchar is converted to int, but the maximum accepted value for int datatype  is 2,147,483,647 and the column conversations.customer_id has a value '238998679919674' that cannot be converted to int, that is what the error says.
You can try to join your table not on

```
customers.id = conversations.customer_id
```

but on

```
cast(customers.id as nvarchar(255) = conversations.customer_id
```

but there is a logical error: not all your conversations.customer_id have a correspondent customers.id, so maybe the join is incorrect at all